Does a Wayland client have to be aware of the specific compositor?
I heard somewhere that Wayland makes it complicated by having apps to know how to draw windows. I thought apps only had to know what to write to the buffer received from the compositor and the compositor handles the drawing and addition of window decorations etc. Am I missing anything?
The drawing library for X Windowing System would be Xlib or XCB. For Wayland, that would be Skia (?). And instead of passing the buffer to Xorg which it draws to the off screen buffer, from which the WM reads it, composites it and draws it to the output, a Wayland compositor directly takes the buffer, composites and draws it. Or, is writing to an Xorg buffer different from writing to a Wayland compositor's buffer, with it being different for Hyprland, Wayfire, Mutter, etc.? If so, isn't there at least a standard way such as using wlroots? I though writing to a buffer would be like writing to a bitmap file.
